# Elasticsearch scripting : Fail to execute .groovy file from curl command line

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I've tried to execute .groovy file from curl command line but failed & received the following error as below. Here is my setup :

**elasticsearch.yml**

```
script.inline: true
script.indexed: true
```

config/scripts/** counterPostCount.groovy**

```
postCount += 1
```

Note : basically I want to plus 1 for the value that I already have for 'postCount' field in my document.

**document : hashtag**

> {
>     "took" : 3,
>     "timed_out" : false,
>     "_shards" : {
>       "total" : 5,
>       "successful" : 5,
>       "failed" : 0
>     },
>     "hits" : {
>       "total" : 1,
>       "max_score" : 1.0,
>       "hits" : [ {
>         "_index" : "hashtag",
>         "_type" : "hashtag",
>         "_id" : "b3ecb430-9fa6-4f41-84da-b79e6a30ef00",
>         "_score" : 1.0,
>         "_source" : {
>           "id" : "b3ecb430-9fa6-4f41-84da-b79e6a30ef00",
>           "hashtagId" : null,
>           "hashtagname" : "helloworld",
>           "dateCreated" : null,
>           "dateUpdated" : null,
>           "postCount" : 2
>         }
>       } ]
>     }
>   }

**curl command**

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/hashtag/hashtag/b3ecb430-9fa6-4f41-84da-b79e6a30ef00/_update' -d '{"_script" : {"script_id" : "counterPostCount", "lang" : "groovy"}}'
```

**error**

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"remote_transport_exception","reason":"[Node1][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"failed to execute script","caused_by":{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_expression","resource.id":".scripts","index":".scripts"}},"status":400}

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, but you have two typos in your query,

- `_script` should be `script``
- `script_id` is for indexed script (hint: the error mentions that there is no `.script` index), use `file` instead for file scripts

It should read like this instead:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/hashtag/hashtag/b3ecb430-9fa6-4f41-84da-b79e6a30ef00/_update' -d '{
  "script" : {
     "file" : "test", 
     "lang" : "groovy"
  }
}'
```

You don't have to change anything in your `elasticsearch.yml` file as file scripts are [enabled by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting)

Comment: Thank you Val. I replaced _script and script_id but received the new error as follow :

`{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"remote_transport_exception","reason":"[WinAppNode1][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/write/update[s]]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"failed to execute script","caused_by":{"type":"script_exception","reason":"failed to run file script [counterPostCount] using lang [groovy]","caused_by":{"type":"missing_property_exception","reason":"No such property: postCount for class: a09142c1ac03bff417e4b55d8b280c22540b28b5"}}},"status":400}`

Comment: There were two changes to make.

Comment: Your `counterPostCount.groovy` script uses the field `postCount` which doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: I do have postCount field in my document under _source. weird. did I miss anything else, Val?

Comment: Can you update your question with your actual script and your hashtag mapping?

Comment: Change your script to `doc.postCount.value += 1`